# Facebook tab like button not working

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-like

I am developing a Facebook page for fans only. When a user lands on my page I am able to determine if it is a fan or not and display content appropriately. In the last few days I have noticed that non fans that land on my page and click on the native tab like button the page doesn't refresh to display the fan content.

What do I do about it? I haven't changed anything on my code to cause this. It just stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't encounter such problems, but if you need a solution, try to subscribe to the edge.create event: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

This way, you will be able to detect if someone clicks a like button and, if the like button for your page is clicked, you can redirect the users back on your tab, like a sort of refresh

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a Facebook bug, nothing in your code should have any affect on the native like button.

Try submitting the bug at http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/